# How to get the count of particular values in a column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the form of

```
dept    name    position             
x        a       Normal Employee
x        b       Normal Employee
y        c       Experienced Employee
y        d       Experienced Employee
```

How to get the count of Normal Employees and experienced employees using pandas

the result form would like to be

```
dept  NormalEmployee  ExperiencedEmployee
 x       2                  0
 y       0                  2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group on the `dept` and `position`, count positions and then unstack.

```
>>> df.groupby(['dept', 'position']).position.count().unstack('position').fillna(0)
position  Experienced Employee  Normal Employee
dept                                           
x                            0                2
y                            2                0
```

This can also be accomplished via a pivot table:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(index='dept', columns='position', values='name', aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
position  Experienced Employee  Normal Employee
dept                                           
x                            0                2
y                            2                0
```

Comment: How to display remaining fields with this. i.e consider if salary is their in the data frame ,how to display salary with this result

Comment: It is not clear how you would want the data to look.  Please post another question with sample data and desired result.

Comment: dept    name    position                     salary
x        a       Normal Employee           25000
x        b       Normal Employee           350000
y        c       Experienced Employee   450000
y        d       Experienced Employee   58963